# FontAwesome precompilation with heroku

Tags: html, css, ruby-on-rails, heroku, font-awesome

I added FontAwesome SASS gem to my Rails app, when pushing the changes to Heroku I got the following precompilation error: http://pastebin.com/2J66S229

Note that I need to precompile my assets and I can't disable it.

Comment: Looks like you are using the Heroku compiler. Have you tried precompiling locally then pushing to Heroku? `RAILS_ENV=production bundle exec rake assets:precompile`

Comment: Yes and I got the same error.